# ActiveMQ starts in slave mode when started with systemctl

Tags: activemq-classic, systemctl

I'm seeing strange behavior when starting ActiveMQ using `systemctl`. The server starts in slave mode:

```
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:46  INFO XBeanBrokerFactory$1 - Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@68bbe345: startup date [Fri Oct 08 18:15:46 UTC 2021]; root of context hierarchy
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:46  INFO XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/var/tmp/amq/conf/activemq-nojournal-persistent-SSL.xml]
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:46  INFO XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/var/tmp/amq/conf/jetty.xml]
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:47  INFO BrokerService - Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/var/tmp/amq/data/kahadb]
[pid: ][KahaDB Index Free Page Recovery] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:47  INFO PageFile - Page File: /var/tmp/amq/data/kahadb/db.data. Recovering pageFile free list due to prior unclean shutdown..
[pid: ][KahaDB Index Free Page Recovery] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:47  INFO PageFile - Page File: /var/tmp/amq/data/kahadb/db.data. Recovered pageFile free list of size: 0
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:47  INFO MessageDatabase - KahaDB is version 7
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:47  INFO PListStoreImpl - PListStore:[/activemq-data/broker-persistent-SSL/tmp_storage] started
[pid: ][main] 08 Oct 2021 18:15:47  INFO SharedFileLocker - Database activemq-data/broker-persistent-SSL/scheduler/lock is locked by another server. This broker is now in slave mode waiting a lock to be acquired
```

If I start the broker using `sudo -u <user>` it starts correctly.

This is configured to run SSL with persistence:

```xml
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" 
     useJmx="true"
        persistent="true" 
        dedicatedTaskRunner="false" 
        schedulerSupport="true"
        brokerName="broker-persistent-SSL">
```

This is the process:

```
/usr/bin/java -Dlog4j.dir=/var/tmp/amq/log -Dlog_instance=ip-172-31-51-195.ec2.internal -Dinvenio_log_component=mqbroker -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=51520 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/var/tmp/amq/conf/broker.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/tmp/amq/conf/broker.ts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password> -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp/amq/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/var/tmp/amq/conf:/var/tmp/amq/../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/var/www/mqbroker/apache-activemq-5.16.2 -Dactivemq.base=/var/tmp/amq -Dactivemq.conf=/var/tmp/amq/conf -Dactivemq.data=/var/tmp/amq/data -jar /var/www/mqbroker/apache-activemq-5.16.2/bin/activemq.jar start xbean:file:/var/tmp/amq/conf/activemq-nojournal-persistent-SSL.xml
```

More process information: starting broker using systemctl. Using netstat i see only one java process which is the broker..

```
tcp6       0      0 :::51520                :::*                    LISTEN      4597/java
tcp6       0      0 :::51521                :::*                    LISTEN      4597/java
tcp6       0      0 :::41320                :::*                    LISTEN      4597/java.
```

SSL is on 61617 which is not in the list I assume because it is in slave mode. lsof only show the 4597 process has the lock file open

This is how the process looks starting using sudo -u. Starting in this manner does not put the broker in slave mode

```
tcp6       0      0 :::51520                :::*                    LISTEN      4838/java
tcp6       0      0 :::51521                :::*                    LISTEN      4838/java
tcp6       0      0 :::61617                :::*                    LISTEN      4838/java
tcp6       0      0 :::45521                :::*                    LISTEN      4838/java
```

lsof show two file lock in this case..one for kahadb/lock and one for
activemq-data.../scheduler/log

I've removed the lock file and restarted. There are no other brokers on this machine

Can anyone give me a hint as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Weird.. looks like the schedule data store is locked, but kaha and tmp is fine. Inspect that folder 'scheduler' for another process having it open, it not existing or being owned by a different unix user id

Comment: the activemq-data/broker-persistent-SSL/scheduler/lock file exists.. I removed it and starting again with systemctl.. The lock no longer exists but I still have the message in the lock.

Comment: This has all the makings of a UNIX/Linux process issue. Look for a second 'java' process. Also, confirm which process has the file locked. See the 'lsof' command.

Comment: I've updated with the lsof and netstat information..